# Fixed text visible only inside one div

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a code like that(simplified):

```
<style>
.contentblock{
background-color:green;
}
.thereisaproblem{
background-image:url(image.png);
background-attachment:fixed; 
}
.fix{
position:fixed; /* text is centred too if thats important*/
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="thereisaproblem" id="id1">
    <div class="fix"> Fixed text </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="contentblock">
    Website content 1
    </div>

    <div class="thereisaproblem" id="id3">
    <div class="fix"> Another fixed text </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentblock">
    Website content 2
    </div>
</body>
```

I need "Fixed text" to be visible only in a div with id 1, and "Another fixed text" to be visible only in a div with id 3". 
When I tried to do it simply by position:fixed; text overlapped in both divs. Using z-index can only prevent 3 from being visible in 1 and vice versa. Always one of texts can be visible in the wrong div. Is there any solution to make fixed like effect but with text visible only in one div? It would be best to use just html/css, but if jscript/jquery is needed then it's ok.

---

there is link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkhsrwtb/7/)

---

Basicly, if you check the jsfiddle, I want other text to be visible in the place of the first one when you scroll down to another div. You can ignore the problem of fixed text being on top of solid blue divs.

Comment: ID identifiers can NOT start with numbers. Also, could you elabarote some? I have read it three times I still don't understand what your goal / problem is. In case your IDS must have numbers, then your CSS must have access like this --> [id='1']

Comment: I added jsfiddle hyperlink. The problem isn't in ids, but i changed them just to make it correct. The goal is a fixed position text, or just looking like fixed position text that is on top(visible on screen) only in a div it was declared in.

Comment: I tried adding position:relative to .thereisaproblem class and then the third div text appears ok. See JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gkhsrwtb/9/

Comment: Yes, third one is ok now, but I achieved that earlier, i need it to work with first one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand.

***CSS SOLUTION***

```
.thereisaproblem{
    position:relative;
}

.fixed{
    position:absolute; // FIXED IS RELATIVE to window 
                       // ABSOLUTE is relative to first positioned parent
}
```

***JAVASCRIPT SOLUTION***

I'll post with **jQuery** but it's not necesssary, it can be done just as fine with simple good old javascript.

All the code does is if the user has scrolled 100px from the top then it hides whatever div has the class **top** (in your case is what you had with #1), and shows the div with class **bottom**. Otherwise, it does the opposite. You'd have to see what's the best distance for you to use to satisfy your purpose.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) { 
     $('.top').hide();
     $('.bottom').show();
 }
 else {
     $('.bottom').hide();
     $('.top').show();
 } 
});
```

In regards to CSS:

```
.contentblock{
   position:relative;
   z-index:2;
}
.fixed{
   position:fixed;
   z-index:0:
}
.bottom{
  display:none;
}
```

Notice how **initially** the div (third div) is in display **none** so that only the first div is visible.

```
<div class="thereisaproblem top" >
  <div class="fixed">
  Fixed text visible in first div
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contentblock">
Website content

</div>

<div class="thereisaproblem bottom">
  <div class="fixed">
  Fixed text visivle in third div
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contentblock">Webs content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without defining actual positions for your fixed text to go, it will always default to `top: 0; left: 0;` of the next parent to have a `position: relative;`. Defining position will fix your overlapping issue, however, the functionality you are asking for to have text be input in certain divs depending on ID will require javascript/jquery, or even PHP.